# headset microphone not found after update to 17.04

Tags: sound, microphone, 17.04, ubuntu-mate

I have a headset with a 3,5" plug, with integrated microphone. [Picture of the cable and headset](https://www.marshallheadphones.com/media/resized/catalog/product/m/a/major_ii_black_0007s_0011_2_major_ii_black.jpg_1900.jpg).
It always used to work just fine. After the update to 17.04 it doesn't work   anymore.

So I check the sound settings. And on *input* there is only one "connector"
[image]

On the *output* tab it shows 2 connectors. *Speakers* and *Headphones*

The laptop is a *Asus VivoBook Pro N552VX-FY166T*
[Picture of the 3,5inch connector](https://ic.tweakimg.net/ext/i/2000959665.jpeg)

What Went wrong, where do I look?

Comment: I have the same problem but I didn't find a solution for it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working following this : 
I edited /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and added the line “options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi”. (A few instead need “options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-dock”, but it’s not that common.) Rebooted the computer and bingo !
ref : http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2014/03/07/headset-jacks-on-newer-laptops/

Comment: This is the same conclusion on SuperUser where almost same question was asked :) - https://superuser.com/questions/1312970/headset-microphone-not-detected-by-pulse-und-alsa